# What is the difference between line search and gradient descent?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent, conjugate-gradient

I understand the gradient descent algorithm, but having trouble how it relates to line search. Is gradient descent a type of line search?

Comment: Gradient descent is a way to choose the descent direction. Line search is a way to choose how far along the descent direction to go.

Answer (score 4):

Gradient descent employs line search to determine the step length.

An iterative optimization problem for solving $\min_x f(x)$ that is currently at the point $x^k$ yields a search direction $\Delta x^k$. Gradient descent does too. The next iterate is given by $x^{k+1} = x^k + \alpha \Delta x^k$. Line search is about finding a good value for $\alpha$. Exact line search solves $\min_{\alpha} f(x^k + \alpha \Delta x^k)$. Since this is a univariate problem, a typical solution method is bisection search (for convex problems).

Answer (score 1):

The following figure shows the hierarchy of some of the line search optimization methods for quadratic forms. Indeed, the methods are categorized based on choosing the descent direction $p_k$ and the length step $\alpha_k$. Just recall that

\begin{align}
\phi(x) &= \frac{1}{2}x^{\top}A \, x + b^\top x + c,\\
x_k &= x_{k-1} + \alpha_{k} p_k, \\[0.5em]
r_{k-1} &= -\nabla\phi(x_{k-1}) = b - Ax_{k-1}.
\end{align}

where $A$ is required to be positive definite. Now, suppose that we are in $k$th iteration of the algorithm with $r_{k-1}\ne 0$ (otherwise the solution is found) and look at the following diagram. You should also be familiar with the following results

> **Lemma**. In exact line search, the coefficients for updating solutions are defined as $\alpha_{k}:= \arg\underset{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}{\min} \phi(x_{k}+\alpha p_k)$. This can be further simplified to $\alpha_{k}=p_k^\top r_{k-1} /p_k^\top A\, p_k$.

> **Theorem**. In exact line search, if $p_k^\top r_{k-1} \ne 0$ then then it is guaranteed that $\phi(x_{k}) < \phi(x_{k-1})$. More, specifically, we have
> $$\phi(x_{k}) = \phi(x_{k-1}) -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(p_k^\top r_{k-1})^2}{p_k^\top A \, p_k}.$$

[image]